# Can we order by DATE as well as group by NAME in Mysql Syntax?

Tags: php, mysql

My client wants to display rows in such a way that Name should be in group but transfer date in ascending order.

```
 $sql = "select staff.Name, staff.Gender, transferHistory.transferDate from 
 staff inner join (transferHistory) on (transferHistory.StaffID=staff.StaffID) 
 ORDER by transferHistory.transferDate ASC GROUP by staff.Name";
```

Comment: When your statement does not seem to use any group functions, why do you want a `group by`?

Comment: Just use 2 order by clauses? `ORDER BY transferHistory.transferDate ASC, staff.Name ASC`?

Comment: That can be accomplished, but if you want to GROUP BY name, you might want to have some kind of Aggregated function, like MAX, SUM, etc. What is the purpose of the GROUP BY there?

Comment: I agree with Ravinder and Filipe: think about wether you want to group or not. Do you want to see all transfers or do you want to see all persons? In case you just want to see one record per person, what transfer date shall be shown with that person? The latest?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the syntax is not right, first you must group by the column you want, in this case, the name, and finally you must order the results... so the code would be:

```
$sql = "select staff.Name, staff.Gender, transferHistory.transferDate from 
staff inner join (transferHistory) on (transferHistory.StaffID=staff.StaffID) 
GROUP by staff.Name ORDER by transferHistory.transferDate ASC";
```

Comment: Because some non-aggregated columns in the SELECT are missing from the GROUP BY, this is likely to return unexpected results. In general, in the absence of any aggregating functions, I think it's best to avoid using GROUP BY altogether.